# What is the preference if reading a single Kanji?

Tags: word-choice

For example the term 人, is the preference for reading it hito or jin? There are no other characters associated with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the time when a kanji is own its own, you use its 訓読み, in this case ひと。

女 on its own is おんな

男 on its own is おとこ

新 on its own is あらた etc.